# Dropdown keep it selected

Tags: php, mysqli

I Like to get a list of battlenames in a dropdown, this i managed. But now i would like to keep one of them selected. But i can't find the right if statment to compare with my $rows.

Thanks a lot

```
< ?php
echo " < select name = 'battle' > ";

while (($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) != null)

{
   echo "< option value = '{$rows['battle_number']}'";

   if ($result['battle_number'] == $rows['battle_number'])

    echo "selected = 'selected'";

    echo ">{$rows['name']}</option>";
}
echo "< /select>";

? >
```

Comment: What do you mean "stay selected"? You need to give some more information on what you expect to happen.

Comment: can you show your html also?

Comment: You're echo is missing a `space`. Atm your output will be `value="foo"selected="selected"` when correct record is found

Comment: what is $result['battle_number']?

Comment: include("connectionDB.php");


$query = 'SELECT * FROM `battlefield` ORDER BY battle_number ASC';


$result = mysqli_query($db,$query); 


this is my query and connection. i dont have any other html regarding to this.

I cant make it selected it gives me back errors, no matter what i try. $result['battle_number'] is the last thing i tried.

Comment: is it an edit form? r u passing any battle_number to this form?

Comment: As I stated in my comment, and see Pupil's answer, the HTML output is wrong. This has nothing to do with the mysql result set...

Comment: @DarkBee you are correct

Comment: thanks for that, but still i got. if ($selected_battle_number == $rows['battle_number']) this was my orrignal if. and this is my error.


Notice:  Undefined variable: selected_battle_number in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\datavis\index.php on line 26
>Battle of the Golden Tooth

Comment: @BorisVellekoop: Well, *where do you define* `$selected_battle_number`?  When this code executes, how do you *know* which "battle number" has been "selected"?  Where does that information exist?

Answer (score 1):

Corrected and simplified code:

```
<?php
echo '<select name="battle">';
while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  $selected = ($result['battle_number'] == $rows['battle_number']) ? 'selected="selected"' : '';
  echo '<option value = "'.$rows['battle_number'] . '" ' . $selected. '>' . $rows['name'] . '</option>';
}
echo '</select>';
?>
```